# MemorySanitzer warns of use of undefined memory in `struct stat`; I do check the `stat` return value, though

Tags: c, clang, glibc, stat, memory-sanitizer

```c
        struct stat st;
        if (stat(python_pkgdir, &st)) {
            qd_error_errno(errno, "Cannot find Python library path '%s'", python_pkgdir);
            return NULL;
        } else if (!S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) {  // dispatch.c, line 99
            qd_error(QD_ERROR_RUNTIME, "Python library path '%s' not a directory", python_pkgdir);
            return NULL;
        }
```

```
==2028==WARNING: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value
    #0 0x56b3c3 in qd_dispatch /home/runner/work/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/src/dispatch.c:99:20
    #1 0x4c2346 in main_process /home/runner/work/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/router/src/main.c:92:16
    #2 0x4c05d8 in main /home/runner/work/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/router/src/main.c:369:9
    #3 0x7f398fd39b74 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x27b74)
    #4 0x43fdbd in _start (/__w/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/build/router/qdrouterd+0x43fdbd)

  Uninitialized value was created by an allocation of 'st' in the stack frame of function 'qd_dispatch'
    #0 0x56ab90 in qd_dispatch /home/runner/work/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/src/dispatch.c:77

SUMMARY: MemorySanitizer: use-of-uninitialized-value /home/runner/work/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/qpid-dispatch/src/dispatch.c:99:20 in qd_dispatch
```

What could go wrong there in my code? As far as I can tell, I only touch `st.st_mode` when call to `stat` succeeded. I am at the point of blaming a bug in my compiler, sanitizer, or glibc.

The only thing I can think of doing with is to unpack the `if` a little bit. Do a `if ( ... != 0) return`, remove the `else` as it is not needed (due to `return` before), to make the code more conventional. That would not change the meaning, though.

Comment: Just do `struct stat st = {0};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemorySanitizer does not instrument all the code involved in the execution of your program. It cannot instrument external libraries, including the standard library, or kernel code.

> MemorySanitizer requires that all program code is instrumented. This also includes any libraries that the program depends on, even libc. Failing to achieve this may result in false reports.

> Full MemorySanitizer instrumentation is very difficult to achieve. To make it easier, MemorySanitizer runtime library includes 70+ interceptors for the most common libc functions.

Obviously libc has much much more than 70 functions, so false positives are inevitable.

Comment: You're probably right. I reread https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html#handling-external-code and https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/900, which confirm this. List of interceptors is https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/e356027016c6365b3d8924f54c33e2c63d931492/compiler-rt/lib/msan/msan_interceptors.cpp. I'm going to try using `valgrind --tool=memcheck` and live with the massive slowdowns.